# Setinterval for different events with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, jquery-slider

I have created my own slider. Each slide has different animations over different elements, so I have something like this for the buttons to change from one slide to another.

```
$('.content1').click(function(e){
    $('#image1').animate({'margin-left': '0px', 'margin-top': '0px'});
    $('#box1').animate({'margin-top': '0px'});
    hide2();  //hiddeing slide2
    hide3();  //hidding slide3
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.content2').click(function(e){
    hide1(); //hidding slide1
    hide3();  //hidding slide2
    $('#box2').animate({'margin-top': '0px'});
    $('#image2').animate({'margin-top': '0px'});
    e.preventDefault();
}); 


$('.content3').click(function(e){
    hide1();
    hide2();
    $('#box3').animate({'margin-left': '0px'});
    $('#image3').stop().delay(1000).show().animate({'opacity': '1'});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I would like now to add an interval for the slider to move alone every X seconds.

I wonder if it is possible to make 3 different calls instead of just one function I am used to:

```
setInterval(function(){
     nameOfFunction();
    }, 6*1000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Never use setInterval for animations, since the timing will never be synchronized. Instead, use setTimeout(function(){}, 1000), and as a callback function for the animation, use the setTimeout again.

Comment: What should be inside the setTimeout function when is not a callback?

Comment: The functions should be identical assuming you want the same animation at initialization as you do throughout your slider. Make sure to set a timer variable too in case you want to cancel it, i.e. var timer = setTimeout();

Comment: So, should i convert my current events into functions and inside each event call a function and then, do then call the function in the next slide function in the setTimeout callback?

Comment: Yes. However, you have multiple animations executing concurrently. This requires some logic in determining which animations callback is the one you want.

Comment: I don't get it working... could you add an example in a reply please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it using `setTimeout` as @BradM recommended.

Im sure there's a more simple way, but here is how I did it.
Here's the code:

## Menu click events:

```
$('.content1').click(function(e){
    slide1();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.content2').click(function(e){
    slide2();
    e.preventDefault();
}); 

$('.content3').click(function(e){
    slide3();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

## Slide effects

```
function slide1(){
    next = 2; //setting which is gonna be the next slide
    $('#image1').animate({'margin-left': '0px', 'margin-top': '0px'});
    $('#box1').animate({'margin-top': '0px'});

    hide2();
    hide3();
}

function slide2(){
    next = 3; //setting which is gonna be the next slide
    hide1();
    hide3();
    $('#box2').animate({'margin-top': '0px'});
    $('#image2').animate({'margin-top': '0px'});
}

function slide3(){
    next = 1; //setting which is gonna be the next slide
    hide1();
    hide2();
    $('#box3').animate({'margin-left': '0px'});
    $('#image3').stop().delay(1000).show().animate({'opacity': '1'});
}
```

## Hidding functions

```
    function hide1(){
    $('#image1').animate({'margin-left': '2000px'});
    $('#box1').animate({'margin-top': '-2000px'});
}

function hide2(){
    $('#box2').animate({'margin-top': '600px'});
    $('#image2').animate({'margin-top': '-2000px'});
}

function hide3(){
    $('#box3').animate({'margin-left': '-2000px'});
    $('#image3').animate({'opacity' : '0', 'display' : 'none'}, function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

## Onmouse over/out actions

```
//when its over, we stop the movement
var delay = 6000; //6 seconds
$('#slider').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);

}, function(){
//starting again the animation (since the last slide)   
    timer = window.setTimeout(playSlide, delay);
});
```

## Main playslide function

```
var next = 2;  //next slide will be the 2nd one at the start
function playSlide(){
    var name = "slide" + next;
    var method = eval(name);

    method();

    //calling recursively the function
    timer = window.setTimeout(playSlide, delay);
}
```

## First call

```
  //only if there's an slider, we initate it
if($('#slider').length){
    //first call the the slider
    timer = window.setTimeout(playSlide, delay);
}
```